# What search can I perform to get a streaming app result on Google?

Tags: google-search

There are reports (see link below), that Google will now stream a small set of apps, when content in those apps match your search criteria. I have yet to be able to produce a Google search that shows one of these streaming app results.

I've tried using the example that I've seen in articles: "hotel right now in Chicago", from both the mobile web version of Google.com, as well as the Google app, but to no avail. The correct answer to this question will look something like:

"In order to see a streaming app result, you must be within the Google App, and you must use the following search: What is Sagittarius' horoscope for today?"

*or*

It appears from this link (www.example.com/GooglePulledStreamingApps) that Google is no longer streaming apps, or is only streaming them to a limited number of people.

I've also discovered (see 2) that this only works from the Google App on devices running Android 5 or 6. Although this feature of Google is only available on Android, I still don't believe this is an Android Community question, because it is specifically regarding how a search on Google behaves.

---

What are streaming app results?

[Google App Streaming: A Big Move In Building “The Web Of Apps”](http://marketingland.com/google-app-streaming-web-of-apps-152449)

[Google’s Going to Make Downloading Apps an Afterthought](http://www.wired.com/2015/11/google-streaming-apps-search/)

Comment: Google almost always rolls out features like these in waves. It could simply be that you don't have it yet. As to the downvotes, I've no idea. Perhaps because people aren't familiar with the new streaming app feature in Google Search.

Comment: Where are you located? If it's outside the U.S. it probably won't work for you in any case.

Comment: @Al E. I'm in Topeka, KS, USA

Comment: For what it's worth, I installed "Hotel Tonight" and "Chimani" and did some searches, and neither app streamed for me. I'll try again tomorrow, but it's likely that this is only a test that isn't available to everyone.

Comment: Al E. The point of Google being able to stream the apps is that you _don't_ have to install them. That's the "wow" factor at play. They are now able to index information within apps themselves, with the help of app developers.

Comment: That's not the impression that I got. The _Search Engine Land_ article makes seems to say that the "magic" is that you can get the data from the app without having to launch it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the clues are in the article from [Search Engine Land](http://searchengineland.com/google-expands-app-indexing-to-find-stream-content-only-within-apps-236288):

> If you have one of the apps above installed, Google will jump you from its search results on Android into them.

The apps "above" are currently:

> - Chimani
> - Daily Horoscope
> - Gormey
> - Hotel Tonight
> - My Horoscope
> - New York Subway
> - Useful Knots
> - Visual Anatomy Free
> - Weather Channel

Further, the article also mentions:

> The requirements are Android 5 "Lollipop" or 6 "Marshmallow" or higher and to be on a strong wifi connection.

So, based on your sample search, you need to have Lollipop or Marshmallow on your Android device, a strong wifi connection, and the "Hotel Tonight" app installed. And it appears you'll need to use the Google app or search within Google Chrome (no other browser).

And if you're not in the pool of people they're testing it on, even with all of this you won't get the results.

Comment: Here's the part I'm interested in: "You will see them if you’re using the Google app, because of a new “App Streaming” feature that Google is also testing." In using the Google app though, and still haven't seen the option to stream an app. I've asked for my horoscope, I've asked how to tie a square knot ... The question remains, what question can I ask the Google app in order to get a streaming app result? I'm running Android 5.1.1 on a Note 5. I also see that my Google app is up to date.

Comment: From the Google App I was able to search for "hotel tonight Kansas City" and right underneath the ads I see the streaming result. http://imgur.com/hFRr2Jb

Comment: I tried the same from an iPhone (searched within the Google app for Hotel Tonight Kansas City), and did not receive the ability to stream the app.