# Does using Android Instant Apps count as installation on Play store?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, instant-apps

As I saw yesterday, Google I/O 2016 Keynotes with an awesome release of many new features.

One of the best feature which I like most as an Android Developer that is **Android Instant Apps**.

> The new **Android Instant apps** lets you access apps from anywhere without installing. It will let you run Android apps as seamlessly as loading a web page. And, it is compatible all the way back to Jelly Bean.

I have a question in my mind that, if it will be accessed without installing then **will it be counted as installation on Play Store?** And **if it won't, then what is the meaning to use it from the developer side. What will be the benefit to the developer?**

P.S. I don't oppose this feature, just want to know how it will work.

Comment: I think don't count and all functionality won't be work by this way. this my opinion. Rest Wait and Watch.

Comment: I guess it will not count installation, as its just loading single page of out application, if user likes it they can install it and then count will be increased in play store.

Comment: I guess it will be similar to [app streaming from Google Search](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/131969/what-search-can-i-perform-to-get-a-streaming-app-result-on-google)

Comment: @AndrewT. Yeah may be.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Quoting from [XDA](http://www.xda-developers.com/google-io-2016-roundup-part-2/) (emphasis supplied)

- > Android Instant Apps is an evolution to the way Android has done applications traditionally. Rather than downloading a full-blown application, Instant Apps allows users to “stream” apps **to try it out** (in reality, it’s a **partial code download**), without going through the hassle of downloading and installing it

So, if it is a *partial download* for *users to try it out*, it logically **won't count as installation**

> If Play store will not count then what is the meaning to use it from developer side. What will be benefit to the developer?

- This allows app developers to reach out to an even wider audience, as they can now project a native Android app experience to the end user with something as simple as a URL: click and you’re in the app
- What makes Instant Apps good for the developer outside of the increase in app range is that they don’t need to build a whole different app. Devs do need to update their existing Android apps in order to get the advantage of the Instant Apps functionality....
- Android Instant Apps extends all the way back to Android Jellybean, so you aren’t restricted to only a handful of users on the latest Android version.

From a developer perspective, I suppose that [Firebase Analytics](https://searchenginewatch.com/2016/05/19/google-launches-firebase-analytics-for-mobile-apps/) also announced yesterday, will be integrated with this. Other features of Firebase Analytics:

- Instead of focusing on page views, impressions or sessions, developers can see what users are doing inside the app, how paid advertising campaigns are performing with cross-network attribution and where users are coming from
- Defining audiences
- Better crash reporting
- Notifications and Dynamic Links to to help developers grow and re-engage app user bases
- Storage- Google’s cloud-to-device push messaging service Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) is being integrated into Firebase’ s backend and has been renamed as Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM)
- Monetization- AdMob has been integrated into Firebase

Comment: Just like portable apps on windows ;D

Comment: Thank you. I am not a developer. I was keenly following conference and happened to see this question

Comment: This is ridiculous. Where are all the negative comments about this "evolution"? This truly makes me sad. Operating system catering to Malware and Viruses. Instead of user security and stability/reliability. To some degree Windows has been doing this for a long time, obscuring software's installation/file and system access/launch points etc. But *this*... it's truly a giant leap forward.

Comment: Streaming content has been there from day one. Games can introduce additional levels etc. Streaming code is another word for unauthorized updates and installation.

Answer (score 5):

> Play store will count Installation or not

Definitely won't be count an installation.

> If Play store will not count then what is the meaning to use it from
>   developer side. What will be benefit to the developer?

The key behind Android Instant Apps is that devs won’t have to go back and create a separate version of their app to make this work. All that’s required is a simple update to their current application — about a day’s worth of work in all, says Ficus Kirkpatrick, Engineering Director for Instant Apps

Google to make sure majority of Android users get access to the Instant Apps feature has made it compatible with Android Jelly Bean OS and later versions. This way the Android Instant Apps will reach over a billion users.